# Bootloader for ARM Cortex-M4F (SOLVED)

Tags: exception, assembly, bootloader, cortex-m

I'm trying to add a bootloader to an ATMEL ATSAME54N19A microcontroller (Cortex-M4F with 512 KB of flash). I'm using MPLAB IPE (Microchip's programming environment) and xc32 (Microchip's compiler which AFAIK is a gcc port).

I've created two separate projects, one for the bootloader with ROM_ORIGIN at 0x0 and ROM_LENGTH = 0x8000 (32KB) and another for the *app* with ROM_ORIGIN at 0x8000 and ROM_LENGTH = 0x78000 (512 - 32 KB). I'm using an app to merge the .hex files generated for both projects into one with the following information:

1. 32KB from offset 0x0 extracted from the bootloader.
2. The remaining bytes up to 512 KB extracted from the app.
3. 12 bytes at 0x00804000 (configuration bits) extracted from the bootloader (could be extracted from the app as well, they're both the same).

Loading the merged hex file with IPE, this is the content of the flash at 0x0:
[image]

Considering this is a little endian microcontroller that uses ARMv7-M architecture, the easiest way I had to try to decode what's there was by looking at the reference documentation available here:
[ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/d/Application-Level-Architecture/The-ARMv7-M-Instruction-Set/About-the-instruction-set)

With this, what can be seen in the 8 first bytes should be a branch to **0x00002E91**. According to the map file of the bootloader, the **ResetHandler** function is in **0x00002E90**, which would look weird (the additional byte) but it looks like the PC is decremented the moment its loaded due to some compatibility stuff that's been maintained from the original ARM architecture. To summarize, that's how it's supposed to be and I can tell it works.

What's at 0x8000 (beginning of the app) is this:
[image]

Pretty much the same thing but in this case the target of the branch is **0x00058E25**. As you can imagine, the location of the **ResetHandler** function in the app according to the map file is **0x00058E24**. Again same pattern (1-byte offset), so we're good.

The problem arises the moment I try to jump from the bootloader (once its stuff is done) to the app.

I've tried a couple things with no luck:

```
__asm__("movs r0, #32768");
__asm__("blx r0");
```

With this I get a **HardFault** exception like the following one:

[image]

The code of the file that contains the exception handler is this:

```
volatile uint32_t* p_stack_frame = 0;
volatile uint32_t stack_pointer = 0;
volatile uint32_t program_counter;

void __attribute__((noreturn)) HardFault_Handler(void) {
    
#if 1
    __asm__("MOVS R0, #4");
    __asm__("MOV R1, LR");
    __asm__("TST R1, R0");     // Test LR (EXC_RETURN[2])
    __asm__("ITE NE");
    __asm__("MRSNE R1, PSP");  // EXC_RETURN[2] = 1 PSP
    __asm__("MRSEQ R1, MSP");  // EXC_RETURN[2] = 0 MSP

    __asm__("LDR R0, =stack_pointer");
    __asm__("STR R1, [R0]"); // Store MSP or PSP into stack_pointer

    p_stack_frame = (uint32_t*)stack_pointer;
    program_counter  = p_stack_frame[6];  // holds the address of the instruction that has caused the exception
    
    /*  Hard Fault Status Register
     *  [30] FORCED  = 1 Indicates a forced, escalated fault from other fault handlers
     *  [1]  VECTTBL = 1 Indicates a BusFault on a vector table read during exception processing
     *                   This bus error is always handled by the hard fault handler.
     *                   the PC value return points to the instruction that was preempted by the exception.
     */
    printf("HardFault_Handler: address 0x%08lx HFSR 0x%08lx MMFSR 0x%02x BFSR 0x%02x BFAR 0x%08lx UFSR 0x%04x\n", program_counter, SCB->HFSR, (uint8_t)(SCB->CFSR & 0x0FF),
        (uint8_t)((SCB->CFSR >> 8) & 0x0FF), (uint32_t)SCB->BFAR, (uint16_t)((SCB->CFSR >> 16) & 0x0FFFF));
    printf("    frame[0]=0x%08lx\n", p_stack_frame[0]);
    printf("    frame[1]=0x%08lx\n", p_stack_frame[1]);
    printf("    frame[2]=0x%08lx\n", p_stack_frame[2]);
    printf("    frame[3]=0x%08lx\n", p_stack_frame[3]);
    printf("    frame[4]=0x%08lx\n", p_stack_frame[4]);
    printf("    frame[5]=0x%08lx\n", p_stack_frame[5]);
#endif
    
    while(1) { }
}
```

According to the value of the HFSR register, and seeing how the FORCED bit active (bit 30 = 0x4000000), you can also see the INVSTATE bit of UFSR active (bit 1) (see the Exception reference application note here from Keil [Using Cortex-M3/M4/M7 Fault Exceptions](https://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf), page 11), and this bit is activated in different cases, including the first one that's in the document:
**a) Loading a branch target address to PC with LSB=0**

If I'm right, what's happening here is that the BLX instruction is trying to jump to 0x7FFF (again you need to jump to the next offset of the actual destination) and that's what's triggering the exception.

However, the output of the HardFault handler shows an address of 0x8000 and I expected this to be address of the instruction that generated the exception. If this was the case, it would mean the branch was actually executed and there, having a value of 0xFF at 0x7FFF (can't be seen in the previous images but it's there), the data to be executed was not **FFF02002 8E250005** (what's at 0x8000) but **FFFFF020 028E2500**. This would certainly cause an Exception.

So in order to prevent this, I tried a couple things:

```
__asm__("movs r0, #32769");
__asm__("blx r0");
```

In this case, the value I'm storing in r0 is considered invalid by the compiler (I'm afraid I don't have enough experience with this instruction set, I'll have to investigate this).

Second try:

```
__asm__("blx #32769");
```

Here I get a different HardFault exception again with the FORCED bit active in HFSR and in this case with the UNDEFINSTR bit active in UFSR.

So my first question is, is this the right way to execute the jump? I think the first approach (**blx r0**) looks good and I just need to know how to store the value correctly in r0 (maybe replacing **movs** and using another instruction?).

And now from a general perspective, can you think of any problem I could have by having merged 2 different apps into one in terms of vectors, stack or PC? In the end what I'm doing here is jumping to the **ResetHandler** of the app and there everything should be initialized again. The content of this function looks like this:

```
void __attribute__((optimize("-O1"), section(".text.Reset_Handler"), long_call, noreturn)) Reset_Handler(void)
{
#ifdef SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_Msk
    uint32_t *pSrc;
#endif

#if defined (__REINIT_STACK_POINTER)
    /* Initialize SP from linker-defined _stack symbol. */
    __asm__ volatile ("ldr sp, =_stack" : : : "sp");

#ifdef SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_Msk
    /* Buy stack for locals */
    __asm__ volatile ("sub sp, sp, #8" : : : "sp");
#endif
    __asm__ volatile ("add r7, sp, #0" : : : "r7");
#endif


    /* Call the optional application-provided _on_reset() function. */
    _on_reset();

    /* Reserved for use by MPLAB XC32. */
    __xc32_on_reset();

    TCM_Configure(2);

    /* Enable TCM   */
    TCM_Enable();

    /* Initialize data after TCM is enabled.
     * Data initialization from the XC32 .dinit template */
    __pic32c_data_initialization();


#ifdef SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_Msk
    /*  Set the vector-table base address in FLASH */
    pSrc = (uint32_t *) & __svectors;
    SCB->VTOR = ((uint32_t) pSrc & SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_Msk);
#endif /* SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_Msk */

    /* Initialize the C library */
    __libc_init_array();

    /* Initialize MPU */
    MPU_Initialize();

    /* Enable Instruction Cache */
    ICache_Enable();

    /* Enable Data Cache    */
    DCache_Enable();

    /* Call the optional application-provided _on_bootstrap() function. */
    _on_bootstrap();
    
    /* Reserved for use by MPLAB XC32. */
    __xc32_on_bootstrap();

    /* Branch to application's main function */
    int retval = main();
    (void)retval;
    
    /* Infinite loop */
    while (true) {}
}
```

At the beginning it's initializing the SP register to the one calculated at link time by the compiler and later it updates the VTOR register in order to set the new vector location. With this, I think the app should start like there was no bootloader and work fine.

Regards

**Update 1:**
Still no luck trying the suggestions introduced by [Nate Eldrege](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) in order to set the value 0x8001 in two steps (load 0x8000 and add 1):

1. Directly in C:

```
__asm__("movs r0, #0x8000; adds r0, #1; blx r0");
```

Exception (UNDEFINSTR at 0x8001):

```
HardFault_Handler: address 0x00008001 HFSR 0x40000000 MMFSR 0x00 BFSR 0x00 BFAR 0xe000ed38 UFSR 0x0001
    frame[0]=0x00000000
    frame[1]=0xe000ed38
    frame[2]=0x00000001
    frame[3]=0x41008000
    frame[4]=0x41006000
    frame[5]=0xfffffff9
```

2. Through a .s external file:

**jumpToApp.s**

```
     .globl   jumpToApp
     .p2align 2
     .type    jumpToApp,%function

jumpToApp:
     .fnstart
     movs r0, #0x8000
     adds r0, #1
     blx r0
     .fnend
```

Compiled with:
**pic32c-as jump.s -o jump.o -meabi=5**

**myFile.c**

```
extern int jumpToApp(void);

int main(void) {
    ...

    jumpToApp();

    return 0;
}
```

Exception (UNDEFINSTR at 0x0001):

```
HardFault_Handler: address 0x00000001 HFSR 0x40000000 MMFSR 0x00 BFSR 0x00 BFAR 0xe000ed38 UFSR 0x0001
    frame[0]=0x00000000
    frame[1]=0xe000ed38
    frame[2]=0x00000001
    frame[3]=0x41008000
    frame[4]=0x41006000
    frame[5]=0xfffffff9
```

**Update 2 (SOLVED):**

Ok, I've found where the problem was thanks to the Microchip Harmony bootloader demo apps.

It turns out what's at 0x0000 and at 0x8000 is something like this:

```
typedef struct _H3DeviceVectors {
    /* Stack pointer */
    uint32_t* pvStack;
    
    /* CORTEX-M4 handlers */ 
    pfn_handler_t pfnReset_Handler;                   /* -15 Reset Vector, invoked on Power up and warm reset */
    pfn_handler_t pfnNonMaskableInt_Handler;          /* -14 Non maskable Interrupt, cannot be stopped or preempted */
    ...
} H3DeviceVectors;
```

Instead of a branch instruction (4 first bytes) followed by a target address (4 following bytes), what's actually there is a struct storing the address of the top of the stack and the pointers to the different handlers, starting with the Reset handler.

What the demo app does is this:

```
// Set the new value of MSP register
__STATIC_FORCEINLINE void __set_MSP(uint32_t topOfMainStack) {
    __ASM volatile ("MSR msp, %0" : : "r" (topOfMainStack) : );
}

// Jump to the application
void jumpToApp(uint32_t address) {
    uint32_t msp = *(uint32_t *)(address);
    uint32_t resetVector = *(uint32_t *)(address + 4);
    
    __set_MSP(msp);
    
    asm("bx %0"::"r" (resetVector));
}
```

And then from my C code:

```
int main(void) {
    ...

    jumpToApp(0x8000);

    return 0;
}
```

In the end, the idea is to load the new MSP (although in my case is the same) and jump to the Reset handler of the app (both extracted from 0x8000 and 0x8004 respectively).

Bear in mind though the problems you might encounter in terms of clocks if you want to reuse the same app in context with and without bootloader. I recommend you to use the internal DFLL (48 MHz in this case) during the execution of the bootloader and whatever you want in the app (external oscillator, FDPLL, etc.).

Regards

Comment: "I think the first approach (blx r0) looks good and I just need to know how to store the value correctly in r0 (maybe replacing movs and using another instruction?"  Yes, I think that's right.

Comment: I don't recall off the top of my head if there's a single Thumb instruction that could load this value, but at least temporarily, you could use two instructions: `movs r0, #8000` ; `adds r0, #1`.

Comment: You do have a general problem with inline asm, though; you can't put separate instructions in separate asm statements and assume the compiler will keep them sequential.  Also, the compiler would expect each one to declare its own inputs / outputs / clobbers, and would not promise to keep register contents the same between them.  Asm code that must stay together, must go in a single asm statement.

Comment: More likely what you want to do is write a stub in pure assembly (in its own .s file, not part of C code at all), have it do necessary setup, and then call the C code according to usual calling conventions.

Comment: I had also thought about this option (first loading the 32 KB value in r0 and then incrementing the register) but I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way. And by the way, movs r0, #8000? Is this literal value defined in hex format?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's decimal by default.  I should have written `movs r0, #0x8000`. (or `movs r0, #32768` if you prefer, which I don't.)